# Current size of a PostgreSQL table (vs disk space used)

Tags: postgresql

I have a table that was recently VACUUMed, which means the disk space it takes is higher than its actual size (what `pg_total_relation_size` might report). Is there a way to tell how much space it actually takes / how much free space I have "in the table"?

Comment: There are two extensions that may be helpful: [pgstattuple](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstattuple.html) and [pg_freespacemap.](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgfreespacemap.html)

Comment: Thanks! Do ou know if `pgstattuple` returns values the include the toast table or I need to run it on the toast table separately? Because when I try to run it on the toast table, it says I don't have permission for the schema `pg_toast`.

Comment: Figured it out: had to use the toast table's `relid`. You're welcome to post this as an answer, so I can select it as the answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two extensions that may be helpful

- [pgstattuple](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgstattuple.html) provides various functions to obtain tuple-level statistics,
- [pg_freespacemap](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/pgfreespacemap.html)  provides a means for examining the free space map (FSM).